# How to link ws2_32.lib with autotools

Tags: c, build, autotools

I'm trying my C code to build with autotools on mingw+msys.

Could you tell me how to link library like `ws2_32.lib` when I use `autotools`.

I think I have to edit `configure.ac` or `Makefile.am`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, in the Makefile.am:

```
AM_LDFLAGS = -lws2_32

bin_PROGRAMS = myApp
myApp_SOURCES = myApp.c
...
```

Answer (score 1):

At the linking process of your makefile, add the library you want to link.

For MingW to link with `<name>.lib`, You may refer to [Specify the libraries for the linker to use](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use)

Comment: I can compile if I type `gcc -o myApp myApp.c -lws2_32.lib` as you said. But I want know is how to create `Makefile` that behaves doing `gcc –o myApp myApp.c –lws2_32.lib`with `autotool`.

Comment: @user1345414 I am not expert at `autotools`, I think you just modify the line `LDFLAGS` in `Makefile.am` to reflect your command line linking option.